How to prevent anything but power button to wake up system from suspend?
I recently installed Xubuntu LTS release: 24.04, Noble Numbat, using XFCE on my laptop. I have really struggled a lot to make suspend mode not do anything to wake up my system except for a short press on the power button, i.e. no mouse movement, no keyboard presses, nothing should allow the system to wake up.
1.) I have (nearly) handled the Keyboard/mouse issue by writing a short script in /etc/init.d/usbwakeup that is launched automatically at startup. Before the script runs, it looks like this:
grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/product:USB Composite Device
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.1/product:2.4G Keyboard Mouse
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/product:USB2.0 Hub
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product:xHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product:xHCI Host Controller

grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.1/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled

After I run my script:
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/wakeup
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.1/power/wakeup

Everything looks like this:
grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4.1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled

This works perfectly fine after a restart, but after some repeated testing with suspend-actions, the settings get reverted to enabled for the two USB devices 1-2 and 1-4.1, and I have no clue why this happens. Does anybody have an idea?
2.) Even more annoying, I managed to handle that the laptop lid is ignored when closing, but as soon as I open the lid, my system wakes up. What might I try to prevent the lid when opened from switching on the computer?
I already tried the following:
In logind.conf, I added the following lines:
HandleHibernateKeyLongPress=ignore
HandleLidSwitch=ignore
HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=ignore
HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore

And in UPower.conf:
IgnoreLid=true

None of that helped. Closing the lid is actually ignored, but opening activates the system instantly. Any ideas?

@guiverc, thank you very much, I am using LTS release: 24.04, Noble Numbat, I have added this information to my question now.

If the script gives you the result on every login, why don't you try to use it in the Startup Application as a workaround??

Depending on your motherboard, you might be able to hard disable the usb wake up thing by telling the motherboard to put usb devices in the "right" (turned off?) power state during suspension (off the top of my head I remember I used to be able to do something like that on a machine, I may be wrong)
